# c# hide Attribute in derived Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, language-design

I have a base class with an attribute and I want to hide it in a derived class. Is there any way to do this other than using reflection?

```
[Authorize(Roles = "User,Admin,Customs")]
public abstract class ApplicationController : Controller
{
}

// hide the Authorize attribute
public class ErrorController : ApplicationController
{
}
```

Comment: For some reason I am confused about this Q.

Comment: If this is about MVC, then please Tag it as such.

Comment: Like not being able to see with reflection that the base class is decorated with that attribute?

Comment: Isn't `System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymousAttribute` what you want(ed)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could override the AuthorizeAttribute with your own class and specify it to not be inherited.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited=false)]
public class NonInheritedAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    // Constructors, etc.
}
```

Now you can specify which class to use, as long as you own ApplicationController.

Comment: I thought about doing this as well, but I try to use Microsoft classes whenever possible so I opted to just remove the Authorize attribute from my base class and add it to each derived controller.

Comment: +1 for `Inherited=false`, not about MVC but make sure derived class/method not trying to modify the attribute properties.

Answer (score 3):

Removing features inherited from a base class violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  *Breaking inheritance* in this way usually rears its ugly head with unintended and unexpected consequences—after it's too late to change the root problem.

So even if there is a way, I'll answer that you shouldn't use it the vast majority of the time.  Alternatives to inheritance may apply, such as containment (*has-a* instead of inheritance's *is-a*) or refactoring the base into a separate interface which both can then implement; or even combine both of these.

Comment: Well, it would of been nice to set a default authorization for the site using the base class. I only have 1 Controller out of 9 that only allows Admins. Since it doesn't seem possible to remove a base class attribute then this is the soundest advice. I have removed [Authorize(Roles = "User,Admin,Customs")] and I will just set it in every controller.

Comment: Attributes are not like class members, and are not necessarily inherited (that's why there's `AttributeUsage(Inherited=false)`). So LSP does not necessarily apply here.

Answer (score 2):

If it was a method/prop, you could re-declare (`new`) the member without the offending attribute. I don't know of a way with class-level attributes.

```
public new SomeType Foo() { return base.Foo(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends a bit on what you mean by 'Hide'. You should be able to revoke the authorization like this:

```
// hide the Authorize attribute
[Authorize(Roles = "")]
public class ErrorController : ApplicationController
{
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do (allow a non authorized person to see the View). Unfortunately, the AuthorizeAttribute first checks if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) then it validates the Roles.

So that is why I want to "Hide" or remove the Attribute from the base class for just the ErrorController class.

Comment: Maybe you should reconsider the inheritance design: Invent a new base class and derive both controllers from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the 'AttributeUage' attribute on your Attribute class, like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited=false)]
public class AuthorizeAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Then, classes that derive from the class where you've applied the attribute, will not inherit the attribute.

Ow, now I realize that the Authorize attribute is not a custom attribute.

Comment: Yes, this is a class created by the Microsoft team in System.Web.MVC.